# Generate panic stacktrace on working process

Tags: go

**Situation:**

I have a race condition problem in my Go server program:

```
go func() {
    i := 1
    for {
        fmt.Printf("I am alive: %d\n",i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        i+=1
    }
}()
```

After lots of parallel requests to my program, it completely hangs up, and even the goroutine in main does not write anything more.

**Question:**

I want to eliminate this problem. For that, I want to produce a `panic` in this state and receive a stack dump of all goroutines.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Run your application with the `-race` option (e.g. `go run -race xx.go`) which will alert you (print the source file name and exact line to console) if data races are detected at runtime.

Comment: It does not help alot in this situation - i have no raceconditions that can be by -race detected.  Thats why I first want to find a current state of a programm.

Comment: you send a SIGQUIT to a go program to cause it to dump a stack trace

Comment: Oh, and if everything eventually freezes, that usually a sign of a busy-loop somewhere.

Comment: @JimB: SIGQUIT it was really I was looking for - it can be accepted answer for my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a stack  trace from a Go process, the default signal handler for `SIGQUIT` will print a stack trace and exit.

There are also some useful settings that can be enabled through the `GODEBUG` and `GOTRACEBACK` environment variables, documented in the [runtime package](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/). In this case using `schedtrace`, `scheddetail`, or `gctrace` may help show what is happening when your program freezes.

Answer (score 2):

#### Race detection

You said you have races, you should try running your application with the `-race` option, e.g.

```
go run -race xx.go
```

which will alert you (print the source file name and exact line to console) if data races are detected at runtime.

#### Profiling

If that doesn't help (races are not detected because they might not occur), then you should profile your app. There is a standard HTTP interface to profiling data, see the package doc of [`net/http/pprof`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/).

Basically `import _ "net/http/pprof"`, then start your app and visit (use your port):

```
http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/
```

If your app does not already start a web server, then you have to do it: add `net/http` and `log` to your imports and the following code to your main function:

```
go func() {
    log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", nil))
}()
```

Stack traces can be viewed at

```
http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=1
```

and full stack traces at

```
http://localhost:8080/debug/pprof/goroutine?debug=2
```

These pages allow you to view full stack traces of all goroutines of the live application without having to terminate it.

#### Other helpful resources

[**The Go Blog: Profiling Go Programs**](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs)

[The Go Blog: Introducing the Go Race Detector](http://blog.golang.org/race-detector)

[Debugging Go Code with GDB](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)